# Subversion hook alternative

Tags: svn, hook

Requirement : My Project uses Subversion and I have a requirement to make sure developers adheres to the check-in comments that are compliant to the Project standards, thereby increasing the compliance number for my Project but the tricky part is,I can't resort to SVN hooks as there is an organizational plan not to implement the hooks at least for the time being.

Thought of writing a custom script that sends e-mail to users for every non compliant check-in but I feel that will be an overkill and I'm not sure of other feasible ideas to satisfy my requirement.

Looking out for any suggestions or solutions.Thanks. Hope I have given enough details :P

Comment: So you need to do a job and you aren't allowed to use the tools for the job? If you're supposed to invent convoluted workarounds to waste time and money, the sky's the limit. I can think of a Jenkins server that updates a working copy in a regular basis, checks modified items and commits a revert if standards are not met. But of course sooner or later timing will fail and you'll get conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to police people's behavior with technical systems is a bad idea.  People resent being told what to do by a machine, even if the software is just trying to help implement policy.

Instead, consider inviting the developers to a working session in which you discuss the merits of good documentation.  Don't just *tell* them what to do, get them to bounce ideas off one another in order to arrive at the policy built into the project standards.  *Facilitate* the conversation.

Plan to have regular such conversations.  Bring bagels and they'll look forward to them.

-Noel

Comment: Totally agree. Most of the programmers are usually smart people with a deterministic way of thinking. If they are adviced to do something based on a plausible rationale instead of a "Just do it, man!", they will automatically take care of doing it right. At least this is my experience.